# Monitoring Openwhisk cluster

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana, openwhisk, kamon

We have openwhisk setup on onPrem on Docker. I want to moniter it via prometheus and grafana tool. How can I intergrate Kamon with my cluster and prometheous? As a DevOps guy, I need to monitor every single point of my openwhisk cluster.

Also, there is a docker image "kamon/grafana_graphite" which may help me in the cluster monitoring. But there is zero documentation available that how can I connect it to my openwhisk cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation inside the docs directory 
https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/metrics.md

Comment: These metrics point out towards kamon/grafana_graphite image, which is 3 year old repo and not working now.